# Font not loading

Tags: c++, sfml

I spent the last 2 hours trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. Some solutions on Google/StackOverflow didn't change the problem.

Here's this simple code :

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <fstream>

int WinMain()
{
    sf::RenderWindow        window(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "BBS");
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    // redirect sfml stderr to this file
    std::ofstream file("sfml-log.txt");
    std::streambuf* previous = sf::err().rdbuf(file.rdbuf());

    sf::err() << "ABCD" << std::endl;

    sf::Font font;
    // this line fail and make stderr crash
    font.loadFromFile("E:\\arial.ttf");
    sf::err() << "XYZ" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The file "sfml-log.txt" is created but it contain everytime the same thing :

```
ABCD
Failed to load font "
```

For the context I launch the executable within the same directory as sfml DLLs.
I tried to modify the font path to "arial.ttf" and put it in the same directory, nothing changed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `sf::Font font;
    if (!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
    {
        // error...
    }`
.
This is working for me, i think you just mess up with the path finding and Window. If you have some issues with Visual Studio you can still compile on Cygwin to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just solved it.

I was compiling with debug settings in VS and was linking with

```
sfml-graphics.lib sfml-window-s.lib sfml-window.lib sfml-system-s.lib sfml-system.lib
```

instead of

```
sfml-graphics-d.lib sfml-window-s-d.lib sfml-window-d.lib sfml-system-s-d.lib sfml-system-d.lib
```